# i want to browse a foreign LVM disk

Tags: linux, lvm

I had a linux box die and I want to try to retrieve some files from its disks.  The disks are formatted for LVM.  When I connect them to another system I can see the partitions and see that one is a LVM PV.  Is there any way that I can mount this thing and browse the file system it contains?

Comment: Theoretically you should see the LV automatically unless you disabled autoactivation or udev is broken or so. Either way you can see if `vgdisplay` shows its VG and if not, try `pvscan` the PV maybe.